# can I include codeigniter in my software?

Tags: php, codeigniter, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter PHP framework in commercial project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229539/codeigniter-php-framework-in-commercial-project)

If I were to make my own software to sell to people, can I use codeigniter as I please? I wan't to create an invoice system and sell it to clients based on CI. Is this possible? or am I violating CI's agreement?

I checked their license and couldn't find much on having CI included in commercial software. If it's not allowed by CI, is there other frameworks out there that do? cakephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question over on the forums, can't get the link right now.

Basically, you can use CodeIgniter any way you want, you can develop commercial software and charge a fee for it if you like.

The only stipulation is that you provide credit to CodeIgniter in the source code and Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`CodeIgniter` is a open source PHP framework which could be used in any project, for commercial or personal purposes. However, you need to credit it at some place over the project.

For more info check this: [CodeIgniter PHP framework in commercial project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229539/codeigniter-php-framework-in-commercial-project)